# Cron jobs - how to prevent sending a repeated notification?

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to send a notification when a certain event is about to happen in one hour.

For testing purposes I currently am having the cron process run once a minute. But I suspect there is a more efficient way to go about this.

I am trying to avoid keeping track of notifications, and so I am trying to just build in some logic so that I can get one trigger on the notification.

Here is my current process:

```
function webinar_starts_onehour() {

    // Get all lessons that are in future
    $today = time();
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'lessons',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
                                'key' => 'webinar_time',
                                'value' => $today,
                                'compare' => '>='
                             )
    );
    $lessons = get_posts( $args );

    $notifications = get_notifications( 'webinar_starts_onehour' );

    // Foreach lesson
    foreach ( $lessons as $lesson ) {

        $webinar_time = strtotime($lesson->webinar_time);
        $difference = round(($webinar_time - $today) / 3600,2);

        if (($difference > .98) && ($difference < 1.017)) {
           // do something
        }
    }
}
```

So what I am trying to do is have it trigger if it is a little less than an hour away or a little more (that is +- one minute).

I suspect my condition can be set twice in some situations and so trying to figure out a more solid way to make sure with a cron that fires every minute, that this condition would be triggered only once.

And if you think this is really unreliable (which I know it is) what would be a pragmatic way to add a table to track this sort of notification? Would I just create a table, say, `sent_notifications` which would have `user_id`, `notification_id`, `lesson_id`, `status`
and then check if there was a successful notification for this particular lesson and for failed sends use another cron to continuously try sending the failed ones?

Comment: You could use redis or memcached for instance. Store the notification and the user it was sent to. Set an expire time. When expiration is gone, the key does not exist anymore and you could send again.

Comment: I think that the table approach with the notifications would be a better one for logging purposes and for retrying when a message has failed. A simple way to prevent another job running and sending duplicated messages could be based on timestamp. I suppose that, when you start to send notifications, you send them in bulk. So, the foreach cycle will need only to run once. What you can do is to create a file, like notifications.lock, with the timestamp when you started and then delete it once you finish. This way you prevent double runs. Hope it helps!